# Stopping a service from another service

Tags: c#, windows-services

I have one service that simply is for starting and stopping another service I created. 
The problem I am having is when I try to stop the other service named TUT from the Controller service named TUTController It stops itself instead of the intended service.

```
  public TUTController()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        observer = new StatusObserver();
        observer.Update += new EventHandler<CustomArgs>(observer_Update);
    }

    void observer_Update(object sender, CustomArgs e)
    {
        ServiceController sc = new ServiceController("TUT");
        sc.Refresh();

        switch (e.CurrentStatus)
        {
            case StatusObserver.Status.On:
                if (sc.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped)
                {
                    sc.Start();
                    sc.Refresh();
                }
                break;
            case StatusObserver.Status.Off:
                if (sc.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Running)
                {
                    sc.Stop();
                    sc.Refresh();
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

The observer is a class that simply check the database so often for a Off/On value and publishes it back via the Update event. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest checking the names and dependencies of the two services.

Are you sure TUT & TUTController are the names of the services you think?

More so, is it possible that the SCM has a TUT listed as a dependency of TUTController (rather than the other way around) and so causing it to get shut down?

Comment: I initial had TUT as  Dependency to TUTController , then after some thought I realized this was wrong and removed it. It look like the change didn't take so after doing clean solution and a rebuild it took. That did the trick Thanks for the Idea!

Answer (score 0):

You can use messaging.

For Instance, there are TUTService and SomeService.
When some service want to stop TUTService, SomeService send message StartServiceMessage to TuTService
In TUTService you implement MessageHandler to process StartServiceMessage sent by SomeService.

in MessageHandler logic, you can have sc.stop()

You can use NServiceBus to implement the messaging